# Many queries to API with javascript and some of them get 403

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get to rest API. This is my react code:

```
var URL = 'myurl&partno=';

handleSearch(){
  var numbers = this.state.newTodo.split("\n");
  var queries = [];
  var response;
  var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
  var responses = [];
  var URL = 'myurl&partno=';
  numbers.forEach((number)=>{
  queries.push(URL.concat(number));

  response = axios.get(URL.concat(number),{
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
    },
    withCredentials: true,
    credentials: 'same-origin',
  });

  response.then(res => {
    parseString(res.data, (err, result)=> {
      var r = result.result.data[0].row;
      console.log(r);
      r.forEach(row => {
        responses.push(row);
      })
      this.setState(()=>({
        responseItems: responses
      }) )
    });
  });
});
};
```

Sorry for hiding url but i don't want to post it. This code getting a values from state and then convert into array. Next it builds queries (concat value and string).

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYdrL.png)

Here you have example of 4 values so 4 queriest but only 2 pass. Setting interval doesn't help (i thought that API is blocking). Is it everything all right with this code? I know from API creator that they don't limit queries.

Thanks in advance

Comment: arent you missing the `?` to delimit where query string start?

Answer (score 1):

The 403 error is `forbidden`. So you're trying to access a part of the REST API that you are not allowed to use. So check with the API admin if you need extra credentials for certain requests, or if the queries that do succeed do not need credentials and hence, your credentials are wrong.

The promise result errors in the console are caused by those 403 responses rejecting the promise. And you don't have any error handlers in place to capture that promise error. SO I would advice to add a `.catch()` block to your code to capture this error:

```
response
    .then( res => {
        // do things with the responses.
    })
    .catch( error => {
        // Catch errors here.
    });
```

The promise errors will be gone now and the 403 results will trigger this `.catch()` clause. So you can then add any error handling here. For example, with the 403, you'd want to let the user know they're trying to query data they don't have access to.
If the response was a timeout, you could repeat the call to the API here. If the response was a 404, you could let the user know that data deos not exist anymore. Et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

403 errors comes from server and are commonly AUTH problem.
Next, your code:

1 - For a clean code try to aggregate your queries with axios.all() or Promise.all()

```js
var p1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var p2 = 1337;
var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, "foo");
}); 

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(values => { 
  console.log(values); // [3, 1337, "foo"] 
});
```

2 - Array.map() provides a nicer API for managing arrays and transforms and let you to forget Array.push() and forEach

```js
var numbers = [1, 5, 10, 15];
var roots = numbers.map(function(x) {
   return x * 2;
});
// roots is now [2, 10, 20, 30]
// numbers is still [1, 5, 10, 15]

var numbers = [1, 4, 9];
var roots = numbers.map(Math.sqrt);
// roots is now [1, 2, 3]
// numbers is still [1, 4, 9]
```

3 - There's no need to parse Axios response, already served as JSON

4 - Don't use *var*, prefer *const* or *let*

5 - Aside Axios.then(), take advantage of Axios.catch()

Answer (score 0):

I was bombing API by using many requests in the same time. Helped using async function